Bigger mouse coursor on some apps since Extended Screen share
I recently tried using my tablet as a second screen for my computer by enabling the "extended virtual screen" feature. (Like this)
I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 (default Gnome Desktop).
Since then my mouse cursor on some apps (Nautilus, Gnome Settings,...) is way bigger than usual. Firefox for example is not affected.
I'm guessing that some kind of scale-value has been changed or something, has anyone had an similar issue or knows how to fix this?
Thanks in advance
